# Installing Zend 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework

I currently have PHP 5.4 setup, can we install Zend 1.11 with it or do we need to go for Zend 2 (have not come across decent tutorials explaining the setup for Zend 2 on WAMP)

I tried installing 1.11, but it gives out a errow while using the zf CLI

```
***************************** ZF ERROR ********************************
In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework
is inside your include_path.  There are a variety of ways that you can
ensure that this zf command line tool knows where the Zend Framework
library is on your system, but not all of them can be described here.
```

Comment: Yes, include_path = ".;D:\data\php5.4\includes\zend-includes"

Comment: The 1.x should work with 5.4.  As for ZF2, as you point out its still new.  I personally would hold off on using it for new projects mostly because of the curve, where I already know 1.x.  Side note: there is a newer version (1.12?) that fixes some bugs and prevents that XEE injection vulnerability.

Comment: hehe, "...but not all of them can be described here."... Could at least describe one, love superfluous remarks like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely run Zend Framework 1.11 with PHP 5.4.

The error you are getting is because you are trying to use "zf" in the command line, but PHP can't find where the Zend Framework is loaded.  In order to fix this, find the `include_path` directive in your php.ini file, and update the path to include where you have installed the Zend Framework.

Don't forget to restart your web server after you have done this!